# Things to do in the Peak District

Tags: sightseeing, children, activities, england, peak-district

I will be going to the Peak District (England) in mid-July - what are the Must Do things, preferably the cheap ones!

Some walking would be good but we have a 2 year old son so nothing too strenuous. Something for bad weather is probably a good idea too!

---

More information as requested :

- We're based in Loughborough and are able to make one or possibly two day trips to the National Park
- wet weather walking isn't an option (I love it but my wife less so!)
- short walks to go and see interesting things rather than long walks for the sake of walking, preferably accessible with a standard small-wheeled push chair
- bearing mind the age of our son, things like seeing animals, seeing waterfalls, that kind of thing would be a good choice

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail, perhaps - it's a big area.  Where are you staying, how far should walks be (time/distance), are you keen for more lake-side walks, or forest, or peaks?  In bad weather are you still prepared to walk, or would you prefer pubs? The more detail the better - at present it's a little broad to be answered specifically for you :)  Great area to head to though!

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. Thanks for the input though - it's an area I don't know at all but have always wanted to visit. I'm a big fan of UK National Parks, so I'm really looking forward to it!

Comment: A visit to Grasmere's Gingerbread Shop would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In May this year I took a steam train from London Kings Cross to Matlock (peak district) and since then they have opened a 4 mile stretch and run regular [steam train trips](http://www.peakrail.co.uk/Timetable.html) between Matlock and Rowsley (4 miles). Price wise it's currently £7.50 for adults and free for under 3.

Also the [Peak District](http://www.peakdistrict.gov.uk/visiting) website looks like it has some good information.

Comment: As a side note, when I checked out the train site I also noticed they had a falconry display on July 15th

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any walks in the Peaks that are reasonably accessible by a push chair, I think a baby carrier is a much more reasonable option there. Also I haven't seen any spectacular things like waterfalls, etc. but I think there are some stone circles (not as spectacular as the Stonehenge though).

I did the [Nine Ladies walk](http://www.carfreewalks.org/maps/216/stanton_moor_and_the_nine_ladies) and it was very nice and not very strenuous (no push chairs though).

For rainy days (this year this will probably be your best option):

- [Derwent Valley Mills](http://www.visitpeakdistrict.com/see-and-do/thedms.aspx?dms=13&venue=6202295), which are even on the Unesco World Heritage List
- [One of the historic houses](http://www.derbyshireuk.net/derbyshirehalls.html)

Answer (score 2):

Having spent quite a bit of time in the Peak District over the years, I wrote up a [list of suggestions](http://www.martynj.com/recommended-peak-district-things-to-do) for friends.  Many walks aren't suitable for push chairs, but you may find that the flat, smooth Monsal Trail (old railway line) works out.  There is a nice cafe / bookshop at the old Hassop station on the trail.  Various tunnels en route make the walk more interesting, as do the great views from the Monsalhead viaduct.

The path around Howden Reservoir, starting from Fairholmes on the Derwent arm of Ladybower, is also pretty flat.

The owls and otters at the [Chestnut Centre](http://www.chestnutcentre.co.uk) (near Chapel en le Frith) sound like they would appeal.

The outdoor swimming pool in Hathersage is very kid friendly, and is warm enough that you don't need a perfectly sunny day for it to be nice.